# A-Star (A*) and generic find method

Tags: c#, generics, point, a-star

I'm having trouble effectively implementing this generic method featured by Eric Lippert.  His blog outlines a very simple and effective means of creating an A Star algorithm ([found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/02/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0.aspx)).  Here's the quick run down.

The code for the actual path finding:

```
class Path<Node> : IEnumerable<Node>
{
    public Node LastStep { get; private set; }
    public Path<Node> PreviousSteps { get; private set; }
    public double TotalCost { get; private set; }
    private Path(Node lastStep, Path<Node> previousSteps, double totalCost)
    {
        LastStep = lastStep;
        PreviousSteps = previousSteps;
        TotalCost = totalCost;
    }
    public Path(Node start) : this(start, null, 0) { }
    public Path<Node> AddStep(Node step, double stepCost)
    {
        return new Path<Node>(step, this, TotalCost + stepCost);
    }
    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (Path<Node> p = this; p != null; p = p.PreviousSteps)
            yield return p.LastStep;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

class AStar
{

    static public Path<Node> FindPath<Node>(
        Node start,
        Node destination,
        Func<Node, Node, double> distance,
        Func<Node, double> estimate)
        where Node : IHasNeighbours<Node>
    {
        var closed = new HashSet<Node>();
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<double, Path<Node>>();
        queue.Enqueue(0, new Path<Node>(start));
        while (!queue.IsEmpty)
        {
            var path = queue.Dequeue();
            if (closed.Contains(path.LastStep))
                continue;
            if (path.LastStep.Equals(destination))
                return path;
            closed.Add(path.LastStep);
            foreach (Node n in path.LastStep.Neighbours)
            {
                double d = distance(path.LastStep, n);
                if (n.Equals(destination))
                    d = 0;
                var newPath = path.AddStep(n, d);
                queue.Enqueue(newPath.TotalCost + estimate(n), newPath);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the distance between two points on a 2D surface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x1">The IntPoint on the x-axis of the first IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="x2">The IntPoint on the x-axis of the second IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="y1">The IntPoint on the y-axis of the first IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="y2">The IntPoint on the y-axis of the second IntPoint</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static long Distance2D(long x1, long y1, long x2, long y2)
    {
        //     ______________________
        //d = &#8730; (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
        //

        //Our end result
        long result = 0;
        //Take x2-x1, then square it
        double part1 = Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2);
        //Take y2-y1, then sqaure it
        double part2 = Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2);
        //Add both of the parts together
        double underRadical = part1 + part2;
        //Get the square root of the parts
        result = (long)Math.Sqrt(underRadical);
        //Return our result
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the distance between two points on a 2D surface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x1">The IntPoint on the x-axis of the first IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="x2">The IntPoint on the x-axis of the second IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="y1">The IntPoint on the y-axis of the first IntPoint</param>
    /// <param name="y2">The IntPoint on the y-axis of the second IntPoint</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int Distance2D(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        //     ______________________
        //d = &#8730; (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
        //

        //Our end result
        int result = 0;
        //Take x2-x1, then square it
        double part1 = Math.Pow((x2 - x1), 2);
        //Take y2-y1, then sqaure it
        double part2 = Math.Pow((y2 - y1), 2);
        //Add both of the parts together
        double underRadical = part1 + part2;
        //Get the square root of the parts
        result = (int)Math.Sqrt(underRadical);
        //Return our result
        return result;
    }

    public static long Distance2D(Point one, Point two)
    {
        return AStar.Distance2D(one.X, one.Y, two.X, two.Y);
    }
}
```

The PriorityQueue code:

```
class PriorityQueue<P, V>
{
    private SortedDictionary<P, Queue<V>> list = new SortedDictionary<P, Queue<V>>();
    public void Enqueue(P priority, V value)
    {
        Queue<V> q;
        if (!list.TryGetValue(priority, out q))
        {
            q = new Queue<V>();
            list.Add(priority, q);
        }
        q.Enqueue(value);
    }
    public V Dequeue()
    {
        // will throw if there isn’t any first element!
        var pair = list.First();
        var v = pair.Value.Dequeue();
        if (pair.Value.Count == 0) // nothing left of the top priority.
            list.Remove(pair.Key);
        return v;
    }
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return !list.Any(); }
    }
}
```

**And the interface that gets nearby nodes:**

```
interface IHasNeighbours<N>
{
    IEnumerable<N> Neighbours { get; }
}
```

This is the part I'm having trouble effectively implementing.  I can create a class capable of being used by the path finding, but finding the nearby nodes is becoming a pain.  Essentially what I end up doing is creating a class that, in this case, counts as a single tile.  However, in order to get all the nearby nodes, I have to pass a value into that tile that includes a list of all other tiles.  This is very cumbersome and leads me to believe there must be an easier method.

Here is my implementation using a wrapper for System.Drawing.Point:

```
class TDGrid : IHasNeighbours<TDGrid>, IEquatable<TDGrid>
{
    public Point GridPoint;
    public List<Point> _InvalidPoints = new List<Point>();
    public Size _GridSize = new Size();
    public int _GridTileSize = 50;

    public TDGrid(Point p, List<Point> invalidPoints, Size gridSize)
    {
        GridPoint = p;
        _InvalidPoints = invalidPoints;
        _GridSize = gridSize;
    }

    public TDGrid Up(int gridSize)
    {
        return new TDGrid(new Point(GridPoint.X, GridPoint.Y - gridSize));
    }
    public TDGrid Down(int gridSize)
    {
        return new TDGrid(new Point(GridPoint.X, GridPoint.Y + gridSize));
    }
    public TDGrid Left(int gridSize)
    {
        return new TDGrid(new Point(GridPoint.X - gridSize, GridPoint.Y));
    }
    public TDGrid Right(int gridSize)
    {
        return new TDGrid(new Point(GridPoint.X + gridSize, GridPoint.Y));
    }

    public IEnumerable<TDGrid> IHasNeighbours<TDGrid>.Neighbours
    {
        get { return GetNeighbours(this); }
    }

    private List<TDGrid> GetNeighbours(TDGrid gridPoint)
    {
        List<TDGrid> retList = new List<TDGrid>();
        if (IsGridSpotAvailable(gridPoint.Up(_GridTileSize)))
            retList.Add(gridPoint.Up(_GridTileSize)); ;
        if (IsGridSpotAvailable(gridPoint.Down(_GridTileSize)))
            retList.Add(gridPoint.Down(_GridTileSize));
        if (IsGridSpotAvailable(gridPoint.Left(_GridTileSize)))
            retList.Add(gridPoint.Left(_GridTileSize));
        if (IsGridSpotAvailable(gridPoint.Right(_GridTileSize)))
            retList.Add(gridPoint.Right(_GridTileSize));
        return retList;
    }

    public bool IsGridSpotAvailable(TDGrid gridPoint)
    {
        if (_InvalidPoints.Contains(gridPoint.GridPoint))
            return false;

        if (gridPoint.GridPoint.X < 0 || gridPoint.GridPoint.X > _GridSize.Width)
            return false;
        if (gridPoint.GridPoint.Y < 0 || gridPoint.GridPoint.Y > _GridSize.Height)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GridPoint.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.GridPoint == (obj as TDGrid).GridPoint;
    }

    public bool Equals(TDGrid other)
    {
        return this.GridPoint == other.GridPoint;
    }
}
```

The List _InvalidPoints is where I'm falling flat.  I can pass this in to every TDGrid that is created but that seems like a massive waste of resources considering how simple all the rest of the code is.  I know this is a lack of knowledge on my part but I haven't been able to search it down.

There must be another way to implement:

```
interface IHasNeighbours<N>
{
    IEnumerable<N> Neighbours { get; }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Edit --
Here's the path finding code:

```
    public void FindPath(TDGrid start, TDGrid end)
    {
        AStar.FindPath<TDGrid>(start, end, (p1, p2) => { return AStar.Distance2D(p1.GridPoint, p2.GridPoint); }, (p1) => { return AStar.Distance2D(p1.GridPoint, end.GridPoint); });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... do I understand correctly that the `invalidPoints` list is a set of tile locations that are not traversable (that is, that the A* search needs to route around)?  Here's a thought: why not just keep a NxN array of Nodes representing every possible tile, and have each node have an attached "traversal cost" that indicates how much time it takes to cross that tile.  Then your invalid tiles are just nodes with infinitely large cost (or, to make it simpler, something like `cost = int.MaxValue`), and A* will route around them just fine.

Comment: Why not generate a complete set of tile locations where each tile has pointers to its neighbors? Then you can generate this set once, store it somewhere so you can get the initial points from it, then just keep using it. Leave any invalid neighbors as null (this won't work if want conditionally unavailable terrain, but you can improvise something along the same lines).

Comment: Jon - that's exactly what the interface IHasNeighbours is designed to do.  The example above, as long as the List<Point> is passed through, will give me that option, but I feel that it is very inefficient.  I was considering having a master class that implements IHasNeighbours but couldn't figure out how to achieve that goal.

Comment: Daniel - yes InvalidPoints is a list of all locations that are not capable of being a "neighbour".  I didn't add the actual path finding code, but I'll put that in.  My problem is less with the actual A Star algorithm but more the implementation of IHasNeighbours.

Comment: The implementation you have isn't quite what I meant because the getters for the neighbors (Up, down, left, right) are returning new TDGrid points rather than ones you can initialize earlier. If you had something generate the structure and that class was responsible for setting the neighbor's (or calling some initialize method on TDGrid) you could do invalid points without passing something around. So store the neighbor as a variable and add setters for Up, down, left, right. The problem right now to me seems like you're constantly initializing new TDGrid objects.

Comment: Jon - So something like TDAllTiles class that contains the list of all possible TDGrid?  In the AStar class this code: `foreach (Node n in path.LastStep.Neighbours)` is what pulls the IHasNeighbours interface.  I feel we're on the same page of what needs to be done, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: The link to @EricLippert's blog isn't working.  Does anyone have an updated link?

Comment: OK, I found it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-one.  Be forewarned there are four parts (at least?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two separate concerns here. You need to represent the pathways between nodes and the nodes themselves. You may find it easiest to represent these two concepts separately.

For example, in the code below, the Grid class keeps track of how nodes are connected. This could be as simple as storing an hash set of the tiles that are walls (ie. obstructed). To determine if a node is reachable, check if it is in the hash set. This is just a simple example. There are many other ways you could represent a graph, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28data_structure%29).

An individual Node can be represented as two coordinates on the Grid, requiring only three values: the row, the column, and the Grid itself. This allows each individual Node to be created on the fly ([Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)).

Hope that helps!

```
class Grid
{
    readonly int _rowCount;
    readonly int _columnCount;

    // Insert data for master list of obstructed cells
    // or master list of unobstructed cells

    public Node GetNode(int row, int column)
    {
        if (IsOnGrid(row, column) && !IsObstructed(row, column))
        {
            return new Node(this, row, column);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool IsOnGrid(int row, int column)
    {
        return row >= 0 && row < _rowCount && column >= 0 && column < _columnCount;
    }

    private bool IsObstructed(int row, int column)
    {
        // Insert code to check whether specified row and column is obstructed
    }
}

class Node : IHasNeighbours<Node>
{
    readonly Grid _grid;
    readonly int _row;
    readonly int _column;

    public Node(Grid grid, int row, int column)
    {
        _grid = grid;
        _row = row;
        _column = column;
    }

    public Node Up
    {
        get
        {
            return _grid.GetNode(_row - 1, _column);
        }
    }

    public Node Down
    {
        get
        {
            return _grid.GetNode(_row + 1,_column);
        }
    }

    public Node Left
    {
        get
        {
            return _grid.GetNode(_row, _column - 1);
        }
    }

    public Node Right
    {
        get
        {
            return _grid.GetNode(_row, _column + 1);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Neighbours
    {
        get
        {
            Node[] neighbors = new Node[] {Up, Down, Left, Right};
            foreach (Node neighbor in neighbors)
            {
                if (neighbor != null)
                {
                    yield return neighbor;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed, the implementation I used is very similar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was the implementation I ended up using, very similar to Special Touch's solution.  SpacialObject is a Point.

```
public class Tile : SpacialObject, IHasNeighbours<Tile>
{
    public Tile(int x, int y)
        : base(x, y)
    {
        CanPass = true;
    }

    public bool CanPass { get; set; }

    public Point GetLocation(int gridSize)
    {
        return new Point(this.X * gridSize, this.Y * gridSize);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tile> AllNeighbours { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tile> Neighbours { get { return AllNeighbours.Where(o => o.CanPass); } }

    public void FindNeighbours(Tile[,] gameBoard)
    {
        var neighbours = new List<Tile>();

        var possibleExits = X % 2 == 0 ? EvenNeighbours : OddNeighbours;
        possibleExits = GetNeighbours;

        foreach (var vector in possibleExits)
        {
            var neighbourX = X + vector.X;
            var neighbourY = Y + vector.Y;

            if (neighbourX >= 0 && neighbourX < gameBoard.GetLength(0) && neighbourY >= 0 && neighbourY < gameBoard.GetLength(1))
                neighbours.Add(gameBoard[neighbourX, neighbourY]);
        }

        AllNeighbours = neighbours;
    }

    public static List<Point> GetNeighbours
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Point>
            {
                new Point(0, 1),
                new Point(1, 0),
                new Point(0, -1),
                new Point(-1, 0),
            };
        }
    }

    public static List<Point> EvenNeighbours
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Point>
            {
                new Point(0, 1),
                new Point(1, 1),
                new Point(1, 0),
                new Point(0, -1),
                new Point(-1, 0),
                new Point(-1, 1),
            };
        }
    }

    public static List<Point> OddNeighbours
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Point>
            {
                new Point(0, 1),
                new Point(1, 0),
                new Point(1, -1),
                new Point(0, -1),
                new Point(-1, 0),
                new Point(-1, -1),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the main program I used:

```
    private void InitialiseGameBoard()
    {
        GameBoard = new Tile[_Width, _Height];

        for (var x = 0; x < _Width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < _Height; y++)
            {
                GameBoard[x, y] = new Tile(x, y);
            }
        }

        AllTiles.ToList().ForEach(o => o.FindNeighbours(GameBoard));

        int startX = 0, endX = GameBoard.GetLength(0) - 1;
        int startEndY = GameBoard.GetLength(1) / 2;
        _StartGridPoint = new Point(startX, startEndY);
        _EndGridPoint = new Point(endX, startEndY);
        //GameBoard[startX, startEndY].CanPass = false;
        //GameBoard[endX, startEndY].CanPass = false;
    }

    private void BlockOutTiles()
    {
        GameBoard[2, 5].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[2, 4].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[2, 2].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[3, 2].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[4, 5].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[5, 5].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[5, 3].CanPass = false;
        GameBoard[5, 2].CanPass = false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tile> AllTiles
    {
        get
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < _Width; x++)
                for (var y = 0; y < _Height; y++)
                    yield return GameBoard[x, y];
        }
    }
```